# How to refresh specific part of jsp page periodically

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I have a jsp which consists a table, The table is displaying some data which is coming from Database.
Now I want to refresh only the table for every 30 seconds. Kindly help me out to solve this issue. Please find the below code.

Note: I don't want to refresh the whole page. only i want to refresh the table in jsp.

empDetails.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<body>
<center><h2>Employee Details</h2></center>
<form>
<center>
<div id="loadData">
<table border="2">
    <c:if test="${!empty empDetails}">

            <tr>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Department</th>
            </tr>

            <c:forEach items="${empDetails}" var="emp">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${emp.empId}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${emp.empName}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${emp.salary}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${emp.department}"/></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
    </table>
    </div>
    </center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so, what have you tried? are you looking for a javascript solution or what? JSP does not have anything to do with the issue as JSP is a server side technology. You could have javascript polling every 30 seconds, or a websocket push, if your server supports it.

Comment: Search for these: window.setInterval, AJAX, jQuery $.get or $.post

Answer (score 0):

```
function refreshFunction(){
  $.ajax({
     url: '/page.html',  //page or method that will return html
     success: function (data) {
         $('div#loadData').html(data);
     }
  });
}

setInterval(refreshFunction, /*interval*/)
```

See $.ajax, it has a lot of useful parameters.